# Use CKEditor image plugin without the HTML editor

Tags: javascript, image, plugins, ckeditor

I'd like to use CKEditor's Image plug-in separately from the rest of CKEditor.

Basically I'm creating a simple tool to edit webpages. Some parts of the webpage will be HTML and thus require the full CKEditor. But some parts will be images, and I don't need the full HTML editor, just the Image plug-in.

Is this possible to do, and what would be the "cleanest" way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor doesn't provide an image browser by itself, so you must research how to use the file browser component that you have picked by itself.

If you're using CKFinder look at the standalone.html sample, like shown in the "enhancing html forms" here: http://ckfinder.com/demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not looking for the file browser (using those standalone is well-documented), but the Image plug-in; the popup dialog that lets you specify width, height, border, etc...

Comment: But that plugin relies on a CKEditor document to insert the html for the image that you select. So you can't use that dialog on its own, it was never designed that way.